# End-to-end flow for Spring Applications

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, application-server

I am a Spring newbie and I would like to have a proper understanding of how a Spring based web application works **end-to-end**.  Good'ol [CGI](https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/nginx-fcgi-1a.png), [PHP](https://carlalexander.ca/app/uploads/2017/06/php-request-diagram.png), [servlets](https://carlalexander.ca/app/uploads/2017/06/application-server-request-diagram.png) and [JSP](https://www.sitesbay.com/jsp/images/jsp-translation/jsp-translation1.png) have been around long enough that I believe I have a decent understanding of the end-to-flow for those technologies.  I am seeking a similar clarity for Spring.

Specifically my question is whether Spring also follows a "container" architecture, similar to servlets (i.e. whether there is an execution environment within the context of the web server within which the business logic runs) or whether there is a different flow altogether.

There is undoubtedly literature out there but I find that it focuses mainly on POJOs, metadata, configuration files, annotations etc.

---

> Based on the comment from @JB Nizet, I did some search on the Dispatcher Servlet and I found the following graphic which seems to very clearly show the end-to-end flow for Spring applications:

[image]

Comment: Spring MVC co,sist in a a servlet, the dispatcher servlet, intercepting (usually) all the requests, and dispatching them (hence its name) to a specific controller. As every servlet, it's deployed in a servlet container. For details, read the documentation.

Comment: start here https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-spring-mvc-framework-works-web-flow.html